# Contents, Flags, Users and Node views

Tags: 7, users, nodes, flags

I am in the process of making a social networking web site with Drupal7. Most of the tasks are done. However, i am stuck at this issue big time. I have created custom content type, Challenge. Using the flag module, i have placed a flag, Accept Challenge, on the nodes of this content type. Users click on this flag and accept the challenge. Now to complete the challenge users, have to post a blog about their challenge. So is there any way that when the user goes to node/add/blog and begins blogging, in the title field he or she has a drop down to pick from the nodes he has flagged. The name of the title should be same as that of node which was flagged. Please advice.  I hope i am clear. If not, please tell me and i would try my best to be as clear as i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could show a list of accepted challenges for each user and link them to node/add/blog with the title prefilled using the [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

You could also create a [node reference](http://drupal.org/project/references) from blog to challenge, use a "select" widget and narrow the option with a view (that's a cool feature of the node reference module). In that view you limit the records to the current user and only the challenges they have flagged.

Comment: For Drupal 7, the node reference module itself suggests to use the new References module. I am looking into that. And, the prepopulate module is still in dev version. Will keep you posted. Thanks